# How often does Kafka check to cleanup the segment files?

Tags: apache-kafka

By default Kafka retains the logs till 7 days or till a particular size (if configured).
But how often does Kafka check if a segment is more than 7 days old?
Is it a daily check? Or is it configurable? If it's configurable - which property controls it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to configure it using `log.retention.check.interval.ms`. You can find more details [here](https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/12/17/kafka-segment-retention/) or in the Kafka [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.check.interval.ms).